# Can't get hidden image to display with .show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vimeo, froogaloop

I'm using the vimeo api to slide a video off the screen after it finishes playing. Underneath the video player, hidden, I have an image that says 'replay'. The image though is slightly bigger than the player so I want to hide the image via `.hide()` or `display: none` in the css and then show it after the animation of the video player completes.

Here's my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".vimeo-container img").hide();

  $('iframe.vimeo').each(function(){
    Froogaloop(this).addEvent('ready', ready);
  });

  function ready(playerID){
    Froogaloop(playerID).addEvent('finish', onFinish);
  }

  function onFinish(playerID) {
    var player = "#" + playerID;
    $(player).animate({width: "0%"}, 750, function() {
      $(player).next("img").show();
    });
  }
});
```

So the first line is hiding the image. And then when the `onFinish` function completes I'm trying to `show()` the image, but it won't work. I should note that when I reverse it and do:

```
$(player).next("img").hide();
```

it works.

Here's my HTML:

```
%section#container1
  .row.video-left
    .large-8.columns
      .vimeo-container
        .flex-video.widescreen.vimeo
          %iframe.vimeo#player1{allowfullscreen: "", frameborder: "0", height: "225", mozallowfullscreen: "", src: "http://player.vimeo.com/video/60122989?api=1&player_id=player1", webkitallowfullscreen: "", width: "400"}
          = image_tag "behind1.png", class: "behind1"
```

And CSS:

```
.vimeo-container {
    position: relative;
    .behind1 {
        margin-top: -27em;
}
```

I've also tried setting `display: none` in the css, but that wont work either. Not sure what I'm missing.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
function onFinish(playerID) {
    var player = "#" + playerID;
    $(player).animate({width: "0%"}, 750, function() {
      console.log($(player));
      $(player).next().show();
    });
}
```

When I log out ($(player) it returns:

[image]

And when I log out `console.log($(player).next());` it logs out the image that I am trying to show.

Comment: Are you missing a tag in this question? That HTML is NOT html, is it?

Comment: Sorry...that's haml - http://haml.info/

Comment: Sure, I placed the log in the EDIT. Thanks.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError`... It seems that jQuery is not available?

Comment: jquery's working fine.

Comment: Are you loading a library other than jQuery and/or loading multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?

Comment: I'm using zurb foundation. The only other libraries would be modernizr and typekit. But I can do .hide() and it works, which is what's confusing me.

Answer (score 2):

According to the jQuery documentation on the animate method [here](https://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> Note: Unlike shorthand animation methods such as .slideDown() and .fadeIn(), the .animate() method does not make hidden elements visible as part of the effect. For example, given $( "someElement" ).hide().animate({height: "20px"}, 500), the animation will run, but the element will remain hidden.

I had a similar need in a project and what worked for me there was to set the z-index of the element I wanted to hide to be less than that of the background.  Then, when I wanted to show (or, in your case, animate) I could apply the jQuery methods to the element *as if* they were hidden (by increasing the z-index so that the element becomes visible), yet not incur the undefined behaviour of attempting to manipulate a hidden element.

Another option would be to move the element off the screen by way of a negative (x, y) coordinate and work from there.  I'm not sure which visually would be more appealing in your use case but mention it for completeness.

Comment: The item I'm animating isn't hidden. It's an image behind the item I'm animating. But you're right. I'm probably just going to have to try another way of "hiding" it.